# Why is my django exception handling not working

Tags: javascript, python, html, css, django

I want to make my django app as user friendly as possible and I want to handle appropriate exception handling cases and have it push out an error message sort of like an alert in javascript. I want to do this when there's no file uploaded in this case "POST" == request.method is emtpy. So when the upload button is pressed and nothing have been uploaded there would be an alert message sent out. But so far the code that I have keeps pushing out an error message that says "The view uploadpage.views.upload didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead."

```
def upload(request):

    try:
        if "Post" == request.method:
            excel_file = request.FILES["excel_file"]

        # you may put validations here to check extension or file size

            wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(excel_file)

        # getting a particular sheet by name out of many sheets
            worksheet = wb['Summary']

        # iterating over the rows and
        # getting value from each cell in row

            seller_info = []
            for cells in worksheet.iter_rows(min_col=2, max_col=2, min_row=1, max_row=5):
                for cell in cells:
                    seller_info.append(str(cell.value))
            return render(request, 'uploadpage/upload.html', {"excel_data": seller_info})
    except:
        if "POST" == None:
            messages.error(request, 'Need upload file')
            return render(request, 'uploadpage/upload.html')
```

```html
<html>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/upload.css' %}">
    <head>
        <div id='banner-container'>
        <div id='banner'>
            <h1 id='header'>MYAPP</h1> 
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-cloud" style="font-size:60px;color:lightblue;text-shadow:2px 2px 4px #000000;"></i>
        </div>
        <div>
        <body>
           <div>
               {% if messages %}
                <ul class='messages'>
                   {% for message in messages %} 
                   <div class='warningmessage'>
                       {{ message }}
                   </div>
                   {% endfor %}
                </ul>
               {% endif %}


           </div>
            <div id='upload-container' >
             <span><h1>Upload File !</h1></span>

             <span><h2>Upload Here</h2></span>

                <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <div id='input'>
                            {% csrf_token %}
                        <input type="file" name="excel_file">
                        <div id='btn'><button type="submit">Upload File</button> </div>
                        </form>
                     <div>

            </div>
        </body>
        {{ excel_data }}
        <!-- {% for row in excel_data %}
            {% for cell in row %}
                {{ cell }}&nbsp;&nbsp;
            {% endfor %}
            <br>
        {% endfor %} -->
    </head>

</html>
```

Comment: Just a small note - you should not be catching all the exceptions. Try to anticipate what exceptions you are expecting and how to handle them instead of catching all kinds of exceptions, from file not found to connection timeouts to json parsing erros.

Comment: You're misunderstanding `try ... except`. It should be inside your first `if` condition if you want to handle the exceptions thrown there. But I don't think that's what you intended. Just `if request.method == "POST": ... else: ...` would do what you want.

Comment: And as the other commenters say, DON'T use `except` just like that. Specify which exception you want to catch.

Answer (score 2):

This

```
if "POST" == None:
```

will NEVER be true.

Note that there are quite a few other issues with your code. I kindly suggest you first do the *python* tutorial, then the django one (both in their integrality), and also check the docs for examples.

Oh and yes: NEVER (I repeat: **NEVER**) use bare except clauses, and NEVER (I repeat: **NEVER**) assume you know what caused an exception. Your current "exception handler" is worse than useless, it's harmful - it prevents you from knowing what went wrong.